# Terraform Cloudwatch Alarms - Configuration of Dimensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

let's suppose I have this Alarm:

```
  resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "nlb_healthyhosts" {
  alarm_name          = "alarmname"
  comparison_operator = "LessThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "HealthyHostCount"
  namespace           = "AWS/NetworkELB"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = var.logstash_servers_count
  alarm_description   = "Number of healthy nodes in Target Group"
  actions_enabled     = "true"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.sns.arn]
  ok_actions          = [aws_sns_topic.sns.arn]
  dimensions = {
    TargetGroup  = aws_lb_target_group.lb-tg.arn_suffix
    LoadBalancer = aws_lb.lb.arn_suffix
  }
}
```

Under dimensions, I see in the AWS Documentation that only a few dimensions for EC2 Instances available are ( like instance ID - etc .... ) . In my project, I am using a Tag called " Type " to categorize my instances to HTTP or APP instances. Is there any mean to create alarms based on those tags as dimensions ? Meaning creating alarms for instances with the TAG " Http " and alarms for instances Tagged as " App " . Thank you so much in advance.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html#ec2-cloudwatch-dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create [custom Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html) based on the default metrics provided by AWS. The custom metrics can have **any dimension** you want. Once you have the custom metrics defined, you can create alarms based on them.

Comment: Eummmm I see. but we have to bear in mind that custom metrics include automatically higher costs !